# webRTC: How to detect audio/video presence in Stream?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio, webrtc

I would like to know the tracks presence in received stream onaddstream callback. Video calling is working  well but I would like to make. audio only call, so I just passed `audio:true,video:false` in getUserMedia constraints, now when I receive stream I cant figure out tracks presence in stream.

How to know tracks presence in stream?

Comment: Did you try getAudioTracks().length?

Comment: how would I know absence of VideoTracks?

Comment: getVideoTracks().length or "a=mid:video" presence in peer.remoteDescription.sdp

Comment: Hope you're setting OfferToReceiveAudio:true and OfferToReceiveVideo:false --- like this: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/RTCall/RTCall.js#L249

Comment: so if length is 0 that should be audio only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To Know presence of Audio and Video use `getAudioTracks` and `getVideoTracks`.

```
function checkStream(stream){

   var hasMedia={hasVideo:false,hasAudio:false};

   if(stream.getAudioTracks().length)// checking audio presence
      hasMedia.hasAudio=true;

   if(stream.getVideoTracks().length)// checking video presence
      hasMedia.hasVideo=true;

    return hasMedia; 
}
```

To stop passing Video in stream change offer and answer constrinats.

```
constraints = {
            optional: [],
            mandatory: {
                OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
                OfferToReceiveVideo: false
            }
        };
```